# как последовательно объеденить dataframe получаемых в цикле?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть `Excel` в которой хранится связанные значения, но на разных листах, из-за чего я создаю `dataframe` в цикле по именам листов, но мне необходимо получить все эти значения в одном массиве, как можно выполнить последовательное слияние всех `dataframe` получаемых в цикле?

код:

```
wb = pd.ExcelFile('D:\Excel_PZ_py\DEP.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.sheet_names
for sheet in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name=sheet)
    cols = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    dfn = df.drop(df.columns[cols], axis=1)
    dfn = dfn.dropna(subset=[dfn.columns[0]])
    print(dfn)
```

Comment: почитайте про метод `pandas concat`.

Comment: Только лучше не последовательно соединять, а накопить всё в массив и потом разом объединить через `concat`. Последовательное соединение может быть долгим и не рекомендуется.

Comment: @CrazyElf, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно накопить все в массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто накопите получающиеся датафреймы в списке, а потом разом объедините:

```py
...
dataframes = []
for sheet in sheet_names:
    ...
    dataframes.append(dfn)
result = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Последовательное соединение может быть долгим и не рекомендуется, поэтому объединять лучше всё за один раз. Хотя в случае небольших датафреймов разницы, возможно, и не будет.

Comment: Большое спасибо!